# Force texture pack or mod on minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, mods

I have a minecraft server with DaddyCheese with the server JAR using Bukkit 1.2.3.

Is there a plugin that would allow me to force a certain texture pack?

I read about SproutCraft which looks nice, but would the clients have to have something additional on their machine to connect/see the mods?

**EDIT**
Since this question has been viewed over 1k times now it may be worth mentioning that you can do this in Tekkit - Googling "Tekkit and SphaxpureDBcraft" seems to bring up some useful info

Comment: Thanks for this update, but could you please elaborate on this a bit in a new answer? NB: I think I read [the Voxelbox](http://thevoxelbox.com/) even supports per-region texturepacks

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of [SpoutEssentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/spoutessentials/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any mod that forced players to use a specific texture pack would also require the players to have something locally, to check with the server and see what pack it's using, then download and activate that pack.

In Minecraft 1.3, a minecraft server will have the ability to recommend and provide a download of a texture pack.